# Where are all the major log files located?

Tags: log

So, if there is some problem with my computer, be it hardware or software, what are the major log files and where are they located?

Also, is there a generic location where log files of the other packages might be located?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5868/which-logs-should-i-pay-attention-to

Answer (score 133, accepted):

All log files are located in `/var/log` directory. In that directory, there are specific files for each type of logs. For example, system logs, such as kernel activities are logged in `syslog` file.

Some of the most common log files in that directory is :

- In directory `apt` there is a file `history.log` which saves all the package installation and removal information even the initial system build as Live CD. You can open this file to see this very interesting file.
- In directory `dist-upgrade` there is a file `apt.log` which logs the information during distribution upgrades
- In directory `installer` the log files which are created during installation can be found.
- There is an `apport.log` file which saves information about crashes in your system and reporting them.
- The file `auth.log` includes information about the authentication activities such as when you authenticate as root user via sudo.
- The file `dpkg.log` saves the low level details of package installation and removal related with `dpkg`. You might be aware that the `apt` system depends on `dpkg` for package installation and removal.
- `boot.log` includes information of each booting.
- `kern.log` saves kernel information such as warnings, errors etc.
- `alternatives.log` includes the history of all the alternatives set by various packages and their removal via `update-alternatives` command.
- Another important log file is `Xorg.log` which include information about the graphics driver, its failures, warnings etc.

Some other types of Log files may be there depending on your installed packages. For example, My system also includes a log files `epoptes.log` which will only be there if you install `epoptes` package.

#### Changes after `systemd`

With the advent of `systemd`, logging is mostly handled by `journalctl` utility and store the logs in binary format in `/var/lib/systemd/catalog/database` file. This file enumerates all logs including kernel, boot and application logs and provides required logs via `journalctl` utility.

Here is a good article on `journalctl` on how you can use it to fetch required log info.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs#setting-the-system-time

Comment: syslog and kern.log probbaly the two most important

Answer (score 18):

In the screenshot below most of the important logs from `/var/log` are shown. In that location there are often other folders from other applications such as `samba` or `apache2` if you have it installed.

To watch a log in real time you can use `gnome-system-log` or, for example, use

```
 tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

All logs can be analysed more easily either with the filter option in `gnome-system-log` or by using `grep` to search for a particular term. For example, if I wanted to find references to my SiS hardware, I could enter:

```
grep -i SiS /var/log/kern.log
```

Most of the logs in the screenshot are self-explanatory, however, here's a few quick notes:

- `auth.log` deals with all privileged actions such as when you use sudo in the terminal or run gui programs such as synaptic.
- `kern.log` records all kernel activity and can be useful for diagnosing errors with hardware.
- `dpkg.log` is a very detailed account of packages installed
- `syslog` contains both information from the kernel and OS information
- `xorg.log` contains information on the (largely automatic) setup of your display
- `udev` is particularly useful as it contains some details about the setup of hardware that could be useful to record for the future.
- `history.log` (as seen in the screenshot) is from `/var/log/apt` and contains the history of your updates and installations.

[image]

Comment: My System Log Viewer only shows me Xorg.0.log, auth.log, dpkg.log, mail.log and syslog. How can I see the remaining ones?

Comment: @green7  You can add any log you want- go to file > open and then navigate in the filesystem to /var/log and select the log to open and repeat for any other logs.

Answer (score 8):

To view system and application logs, you can use the "Log File Viewer" application.  Hit F2 to open your dash, then type **log** and select the **Log File Viewer** application.

More information:
http://www.howtogeek.com/117878/how-to-view-write-to-system-log-files-on-ubuntu/