# Performance issues after upgrading to 13.04

Tags: 13.04, games, performance

I've recently upgraded to 13.04 from 12.04 and I've experienced some performance issues with games (mostly) I wasn't having with 12.04, relatively simple games like xonotic freeze my system after an hour or so and I have to force shut down the system.

Specs:

Inter I7 2.2 GHz
4Gb ram
GeForce GT 540M

I've tried running the games with primusrun, optirun and without them, all the same result. If I try to run them in the lxde desktop I get slightly less problems, but the desktop itself is presenting a lot of bugs and programs constantly freeze.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've got an overheating issue, possibly caused by dust and debris clogging up the aluminum cooling fins around the fan(s). You can search for any answers having the word *Psensor* in them if you want to find out more about how to monitor your hardware temperatures. I don't think that overheating is your problem though, because it often causes crashing and your problem is freezing.

What *does* often cause freezing is a failing graphics card. If your computer has a graphics card and you are fortunate enough to have a spare graphics card that you can temporarily swap with your GeForce GT 540M, then you can test this possibility for yourself.

If neither of these two possibilities proves to be the cause of your performance issues, then at least you will have narrowed down the range of possible causes of your performance issues. What would help you in this case is to take a look at the answers to [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes).

Comment: The Computer does seem to be overheating a bit, but it has done that for a while now, and only after the upgrade is the system freezing. I do not have an extra graphics card, is there any other way to check if the card is failing?

Comment: The next best thing that you could do is to remove the graphics card and test it in another computer, preferably when you are playing a game. However this has a possible problem associated with it, because you would also have to install the driver for your graphics card in the second computer in order to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using both `nvidia-current-updates` and the `mesa-utils` packages?

To install Nvidia drivers, use the following at the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`

To remove all Nvidia drivers and install mesa-utils:

`sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current nvidia-graphics-drivers`
`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`
`sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

Comment: Also, monitoring and setting alarms with [Psensor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/psensor/) may point you closer in the direction of _which_ component is overheating. Unless you solely upgraded your GPU, and had been running the same OS with no issues previously, something else may be overheating.

Comment: And finally, it may be beneficial to [check the logs](http://askubuntu.com/a/186280/159363).

Comment: The system is in fact overheating, but this can't be the cause because it was also overheating with ubuntu 12.04 but not freezing.