# System hangs on logout after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: logout

This is the first time I'm having problems during Ubuntu upgrade.
I have nothing to do except pressing the power button until shutdown in the black screen when I choose to Log out from the session indicator menu.
Any ideas that can help me out will be much appreciated. I hope I don't have to do a clean install to get rid of this minor problem.

Comment: have you checked the log files for causing the issue ?

Comment: I have no idea about log files unfortunately; which one should I look?

Comment: i think dmesg can help you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/186276/where-are-all-the-major-log-files-located

Comment: Thanks, but if only I knew what to look for in there ;-)

Comment: This is happening to me too. I don't know how to fix it yet but if you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 (any "F" key 1-6 really) you can log into a terminal and run `sudo service lightdm restart` to restart your session without having to power off the machine.

Comment: @Insperatus: Thanks for the tip, but as far as I can remember now, I couldn't even get a terminal screen, so in the end, after also seeing many other flaws, deficiencies, bugs, etc. on a clean install of 13.10 in another machine, I decided to switch back to Ubuntu 13.04 which I had saved using **Clonezilla**.