# System activities recording

Tags: system, architecture, cpu-architecture

Is there any tool (or commands) available for Ubuntu which can record all the activities happening in system up-to thread level/architechture level? I need to understand and solve various of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look, please, at a possible answer for your question listed on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186276/where-are-all-the-major-log-files-located). It is not a piece of software that you actually need but full access to all relevant log files for your operating system.

If it is an application that you want rather than manually check log files you can install [Activity Log Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/activity-log-manager/), a graphical user interface which lets you control what gets logged by Zeitgeist. Read [the following article](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/controlling_privacy_setting_ubuntu_gnome_activity_log_manager) to see in detail how to install and use this (Gnome) Activity Log Manager.