# fresh installed ubuntu excruciatingly slow boot up

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, live-usb

This is a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 from a usb stick on a SSD with absolutely nothing else on it (not dual boot). I did an `apt-get update/upgrade` and nothing else. There are two problems.

1. it doesn't shut down. Left on the ubuntu purple screen for ~half hr, still not shut.
2. When I did a hard power off and reboot, it took close to 10 min to come to the login screen.

Additional Info :
The box has two Nvidia GTX cards (980 Ti and 660 Ti). Not sure if that's relevant.

I found others with the same problem. The advice is to look at `dmesg' and look for large gaps. I saved it to a file and inspected the entries, and found most of the time it's working on this single line,

```
[  506.565354] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
```

Of the 10 min boot time, this single activity probably accounted for ~8 min of it. I thought the OS is now on the SSD, why is it referencing the USD device?

And how to fix these two issues.

## EDIT

Here is more from `dmesg`. From around 3 sec, this usb thing showed up,

```
[ 2.659072] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.702755] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: DRM: allocated 1024x768 fb: 0x60000, bo ffff89c7a234b400
[    2.702824] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: fb1: nouveaufb frame buffer device
[    2.702827] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:04:00.0 on minor 1
[    2.837785] ata12: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.055289] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    3.103061] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.547018] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    3.990977] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    4.434935] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    4.878894] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[    5.322852] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[    5.766809] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
.....
[  151.389061] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 87 using xhci_hcd
[  151.833019] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 88 using xhci_hcd
[  152.082222] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[  152.082380] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[  152.082536] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <myUBU1604>.
```

Then it starts again at 153.3 sec, all the way to end of file.

```
[  504.367391] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 125 using xhci_hcd
[  504.811344] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 126 using xhci_hcd
[  505.255296] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 127 using xhci_hcd
[  505.699564] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  506.143213] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  506.587169] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
```

## EDIT 2 Error/Fail

Here are the lines that say `fail` or `error`,

```
[ 152.496197] EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
[  152.496801] b43-phy1 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 12, Type 11 (AC), Revision 1)
[  152.496810] b43: probe of bcma0:1 failed with error -95
....
[  152.520155] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cf.hcd failed with error -2
....
[  152.218946] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
....
[    1.567537] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to create encoder 1/8/0: -19
....
[    1.770027] ata1.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying unqueued
```

Comment: Do you have anything plugged into your USB port at all that is not a mouse or keyboard?  If you do, try booting it up without it plugged into see if that might make any difference.

Comment: @Terrance Noop. Absolutely none. That's what makes this really curious

Comment: Have you looked at the .log files for any errors, or found any high priority processes in htop

Comment: @hellomoto Not sure where to look for these .log files. Pls give pointer. I didn't have htop installed yet, but have since.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186276/where-are-all-the-major-log-files-located here you go, I usually start with the /var/log/kern.log though

Comment: @hellomoto There are close to 29,000 lines in kern.log, i see this `usb 3-1` appeared there, too. Other than that, not sure what to look for.

Comment: egrep –color ‘failed.*high-speed|error.*usb’  /var/log/kern.log

Comment: @hellomoto Added the fail/error lines above. Not exhaustive listing, but i hope that elucidates the problem.

Comment: As an alternative you could just use "echo '3-1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/devices/usb/unbind" to disable it, and bind to enable it, or there's always systemd-analyze critical-chain

Comment: Have you tried apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get autoremove to see if there was an overwrite fix for it

Comment: @hellomoto Update & Upgrade quite a few times. No autoremove though. I'm at an impasse, and may go back to 14.04 if no solution is found, which never had these annoying problems.

Comment: I found this on unix it should help with the issue :) https://superuser.com/questions/668911/what-are-usb-device-resets

Comment: @Terrance I forgot I did have a wireless mouse on a USB port. It might be checking the mouse status.

Comment: Yeah, it could be checking on the mouse status or the USB controller itself.  Try without the controller for the mouse in.  That is just interesting though that it would cycle all the way through all 127 devices during boot up.  That is one thing that has thrown me for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've narrowed down the problems to a few possibilities:

1. Someone suggested my motherboard may be dead, or has problem(s);
2. 16.04 specific issue, e.g some new drivers have been added to this LTS and they no longer work with my hardware;

To confirm/reject 1), I wipped out ubuntu and installed Windows 7. I am able to boot up and shut down the machine in seconds. Win 7 did not detect any hardware problem. No error message, no choke, very smooth.

Conclusion : Motherboard is OK, or at least for Win 7.

To investigate whether this is specific to 16.04, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from a live-USB thumb drive along with my existing 16.04. I then boot into 14.04 and ran into exactly *same* issue. Showing splash, the dreaded line showed up again,

```
[  505.255296] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 127 using xhci_hcd
```

The device number goes to 127, then repeated three times. This led me to think the problem is not specific to 16.04, thus 2) is rejected.

However, i'm really scratching my head now because just a week ago, I was using 14.04 on this box (exact same hardware) without any issue. In fact, I've been running 14.04 for nearly two yrs without ever encountered these problems.

The driver experts please weigh in on this.