# Ubuntu 17.04 freezes all time on Acer Aspire E15

Tags: performance

I recently deleted windows and installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop Acer Aspire e 15. Everything was fine the 1st day. I set up everything, installed some programs, adjusted some settings.

On the second day the system started to freeze. I can't use my laptop for more than 10 minutes without it freezing. I can't move the mouse or use the keyboard and I have to force shutdown.

I tried a solution I found to edit the file `/etc/default/grub` but it didn't work.

What else can I try?

Here is the syslog file. The system crashed 22:24:48

```
Aug 28 22:21:30 insinsidious-Aspire-E5-523G anacron[839]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
Aug 28 22:24:34 insinsidious-Aspire-E5-523G kernel: [  873.881575] AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out
Aug 28 22:24:34 insinsidious-Aspire-E5-523G kernel: [  874.033248] AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out
Aug 28 22:24:34 insinsidious-Aspire-E5-523G kernel: [  874.034339] AMD-Vi: Event logged [
Aug 28 22:24:34 insinsidious-Aspire-E5-523G kernel: [  874.034343] IO_PAGE_FAULT device=03:00.0 domain=0x0001 address=0x00000000ff4140c0 flags=0x0050]
Aug 28 22:24:34 insinsidious-Aspire-E5-523G keAug 28 22:26:19 insinsidious-Aspire-E5-523G rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="732" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug 28 22:26:19 insinsidious-Aspire-E5-523G rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
```

Comment: what did you do to `/etc/default/grub`? This [System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](//askubuntu.com/a/803649)? If it's not a Bay Trail processor, that won't work. I think you need to tell us your graphics card and CPU.

Comment: First you need to identify your hardware, could be anything from a poor graphics driver to a bad hard drive to a bad wireless driver. Second you need to describe what you mean by "adjusted some settings" . Third sounds as if you may be making things worse, what and why are you editing `/etc/default/grub` ? To what end and why ?

Comment: i edited file and changed 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" 
to 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"

Comment: and did you run `sudo update-grub` after doing so?

Comment: About my hardware:
8GB RAM - AMD DUAL CORE A9-9410 UP TO 3.5GHZ - AMD RADEON R5 M430 2GB

Comment: No i didn't should i run it now?

Comment: I didn't change any sensitive settings just typical settings like apearence mouse keyboard etc. As i said i am really begginer and i dont know how to use this os yet. Also i noticed that everytime it crashed i was using mozilla or chromium

Comment: Freezing is difficult to debug. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash . I would start by running firefox / chromium from the terminal and look in the logs for errors. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/186276/where-are-all-the-major-log-files-located

Comment: I suggest you to do this: 1) Boot up your system, and annotate exact time "hh:mm:ss" of freezing. 2) Boot with live Ubuntu, go to /var/log/syslog from your laptop hd and look what happened at this very time. If you prefer, post it here.

Comment: @TOnyMontana any time you change `/etc/default/grub` you need to run `sudo update-grub`, so that the configuration will be written to GRUB's script. If you don't do it, the changes to the file have no effect

Comment: Thanks for your respond. :) i post the syslog you told me, take a look if you can

Comment: 8G RAM... how much swap? Show me `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info. Undo the change you made to /etc/default/grub, as it is only if you had an Intel processor... and you don't.

Comment: @heynnema The swap partition is 7.46GB and it's all unused as gparted says..

Comment: @TOnyMontana see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289346

Comment: @TOnyMontana I think I have exactly the same issue, every time it crashes I was browsing the web in Opera. I wonder if you have found a solution or the root cause to it? I have AMD Ryzen 1600 + nVidia 1060 as my desktop. Thanks!