# Upgrade to 22.04 failed - kind of

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

I've just upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04. Everything went well. Had one issue regarding Firefox, but the install process seemed to resolve that. Finally got to reboot to finalise install. Login screen appeared and logged in ok.

The desktop displayed, but I can do nothing at this point - the mouse pointer does not move, the keyboard doesn't function. The only thing I can do is hold down the power button to shut the computer down. I've tried restarting a number of times with the same outcome.

I started in recovery mode, which way successful, but didn't really know what to do there, so did file system check, which completed with no errors. Continued with boot and everything was working, but graphics all wrong as was suggested would happen by the recovery mode. So I rebooted but the same happened as before - I can't do anything.

If anyone has an idea of how I can resolve this issue, if be very happy to here from you.

Comment: Can you access your logs? Those will generally tell you what went wrong. If not, then there's not enough troubleshooting information to make this question answerable; back up your data and reinstall.

Comment: Honestly I'm not very tech savvy, so not sure where to access my logs. Strangely, the system works if I use the continue boot option from the recovery menu, but with incorrect graphics settings. If I do a full reboot, the graphics settings are correct, but no access. Well, the mouse is actually active for about 30 seconds after logging in, so if I can figure out what loads at that point and disable it, maybe that would resolve the problem

Comment: "*not sure where to access my logs*" : https://askubuntu.com/questions/186276/where-are-all-the-major-log-files-located

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at boot.log and see if I can figure out what is going on